# Detecting a Keypress outside Vb6

Tags: vb6

I am currently modifying a really old system running Windows Server 2k. One of the requirements I am working on is to block off keyboard presses at a certain window of another program which we can't modify.

Generally my process was fine as I detect keypresses and then terminate the window if they occur, However the only working code that I have found and worked with causes many issues when sometimes Control/Windows Key/etc gets stuck and the entire system tends to act out weird. This is the Code I am using for the Hook:

```
Public Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Public Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowsHook Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookA" (ByVal nFilterType As Long, ByVal pfnFilterProc As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Global Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13

Public hook As Long

Public Const HC_ACTION = 0
Type HookStruct
    vkCode As Long
    scancode As Long
    FLAGS As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

Public active As Boolean
Public value As String

Public Function myfunc(ByVal code As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Dim kybd As HookStruct

    myfunc = True


    If code = HC_ACTION And wParam <> 257 Then
            If active Then

            'SendKeys "{ESC}"
            'MsgBox ("keypressed")
            End If

        myfunc = CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam)
    ElseIf code < 0 Then
        myfunc = CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam)
    End If

End Function
```

Generally the code IS working, However if you press Control, Alt or Windows key then the entire system tends to go haywire.

Is there a better method to detect those key presses outside the system/in a specific window even possibly, Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that ended up working without the issues:

```
Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13&
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0&
Private Const LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1&
Private Const LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10&
Private Const LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20&
Private Const LLKHF_UP = &H80&

Private Const VK_RIGHT = &H27
Private Const VK_LEFT = &H25
Private Const VK_RSHIFT = &HA1

Private Type KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
  vkCode As Long
  scanCode As Long
  FLAGS As Long
  time As Long
  dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDest As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal cb As Long)
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Public value As String
Public active As Boolean

Public Function HookKeyboard() As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrorHookKeyboard
    m_hDllKbdHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, AddressOf LowLevelKeyboardProc, App.hInstance, 0&)
    HookKeyboard = m_hDllKbdHook
    Exit Function
ErrorHookKeyboard:
    MsgBox Err & ":Error in call to HookKeyboard()." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Warning"
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Sub UnHookKeyboard()
    On Error GoTo ErrorUnHookKeyboard
    UnhookWindowsHookEx (m_hDllKbdHook)
    Exit Sub
ErrorUnHookKeyboard:
    MsgBox Err & ":Error in call to UnHookKeyboard()." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Warning"
    Exit Sub
End Sub


Public Function LowLevelKeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Static kbdllhs As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    If nCode = HC_ACTION Then
        Call CopyMemory(kbdllhs, ByVal lParam, Len(kbdllhs))
                If active Then

            MsgBox ("keypressed")
            End If

    End If
```

I just need to call HookKeyboard/UnhookKeyboard in the main form

Answer (score 1):

See the following thread: [Detect keypress outside your application](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?515051-RESOLVED-VB6-Detect-keypress-outside-your-application)

You can try these two other approaches to see if they are more stable:

RegisterHotKey, a function that defines a system-wide hot key:

```
Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterHotKey" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal id As Long, ByVal fsModifiers As Long, ByVal vk As Long) As Long
```

or GetAsyncKeyState, a function that determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState:

```
Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetAsyncKeyState" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
```

You could run a timer and continuously check GetAsyncKeyState to see if the key(s) you are looking for have been pressed:

```
Private Sub tmrKeyPressCheck_Timer()
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    For iCounter = 64 To 90
        If CheckKey(iCounter) Then
            txtKeyPressLog.Text = Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now) & ": " & Chr(iCounter) & vbCrLf & txtKeyPressLog.Text
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Function CheckKey(ByVal p_lngKey As Long) As Boolean
    Dim iReturn As Integer

    iReturn = GetAsyncKeyState(p_lngKey)

    CheckKey = (iReturn <> 0)

End Function
```

Comment: That would work if I look for a specific key, however neither can help when I need to detect any keypress

Comment: I added an example that looks for any of the letter keys which you could extend to all Virtual Key codes. This should essentially detect any key a user is pressing outside your app. I set my Timer's Interval to 100 milliseconds in my test.

Comment: It is somewhat buggy for my use as it seems to sometimes randomly fire up without any keys pressed, I will post the code that ended up working for me, But upvoted for the answer nonetheless

Comment: Maybe it's capturing some other [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) like Mouse button clicks or Windows keys? The loop in my example goes from 64 to 90 and that should only catch keys A-Z.

Comment: Maybe, I will give it another test while adjusting some other stuff to check, I got my solution working but It doesnt hurt to know more :)